# Find count of triples in a list

Tags: python, algorithm, list, structure

I'm given a list and I am to give a count of all possible triples in that list, where (i < j < k) and i divides into j and j divides into k, such as (1,2,4), and it should work where the length of the given list is between 2 and 2000 inclusive, and the elements within the list are between 1 and 999999 inclusive. If no tuples are found return 0.

**Example case 1:**

```
input: L = [1,1,1]
# code should find: Only one tuple found
output: 1
```

**Example case 2:**

```
input: L = [1,2,3,4,5,6] 
# code should find: triples are (1,2,4) , (1,2,6), and (1,3,6)
output: 3
```

Comment: So far i have tried maybe creating a Graph with 3 lists that each have an edge where each index is a vertex

Comment: AFAICT, the first output should be 0. There are no tuples where *i < j < k*.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with list comprehension like this:

```
>>> [(i, j, k) for i in L for j in L for k in L if k > j > i and j % i == 0 and k % j == 0]
[(1, 2, 4), (1, 2, 6), (1, 3, 6)]
```

**Edit**

This is a longer version:

```
tups = []
for i in L: 
    for j in L: 
        for k in L:
            if k > j > i and j % i == 0 and k % j == 0:
                tups.append((i, j, k))
```

Comment: is there any way to break this down into a more comprehensive block of code? Sorry about the inconvinience

Comment: @SergioChecoNuñez See update - is this what you meant?

Comment: YES! thank you. Now i notice this works great with most cases, but what about the first case where all are 1's it should return return 1, but your code provides an empty list

Comment: @SergioChecoNuñez Which first case? Your two cases are identical, BTW.

Comment: oh sorry about that ok i fixed it also i saw that i forgot to add one more thing if there are no tuples return 0, but it seems your algorithm does that.

Comment: @SergioChecoNuñez I think it contradicts your requirements: you specify that you want *i < j < k*. 0 tuples is the correct answer, no?